# javaScript: coffee machine simulator, problem with methods and collecting values

Tags: javascript, object, methods, javascript-objects

I have this simulation JavaScript coffee machine to make and I'm having problem with two methods, one of which adds water (coffee eg.) and other that empty's it.
This is what I got for first method:

```
let coffeeMachine = {
                water: 400,
                coffee: 10,
                milk: 100,
                credit: 100,

waterStatus: function () {
                    document.getElementById('water-status').innerText = this.water;
                },

addWater: function () {
                    let addWater = prompt('Unesite kolicinu vode koju zelite da dodate');

                if (addWater === null || addWater.trim().length === 0) {
                    alert('Morate uneti koliko vode zelite');
                    return;
                } else if (isNaN(addWater) || addWater.startsWith('-') || addWater % 1 !== 0) {
                    alert('Unos mora biti pozitivna brojcana vrednost');
                    return;
                } else if (this.water < 400) {
                    addWater = Number(addWater);
                    this.water += addWater;
                } else {
                    alert('Maksimalan unos vode je 400');
                    return;
                }
                this.waterStatus();
            },
```

Problem with this one is that the total value can not be greater that 400, and it only works when I first enter the value that is greater than 400 (alert pops up), but if add 100, and than 500 it will write it (600), not considering the condition.
Is it that I'm not creating new variable that will collect the sum of this.water and addWather, or I'm missing something else?

Second method needs to empty water and check if the current status of the water is bigger than the value we forwarder to prompt.
I have this:

```
emptyWater: function (water) {
                    if (this.water > addWater) {
                        this.water -= addWater;
                        this.waterStatus(water);
                        document.getElementById('message').innerText = 'Pouring water';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById('message').innerText = 'Machine is out of water \n';
                    }
                },
```

In the object itself I have predefined values for water, coffee eg.

Those values I collected in water status function, but did I not made it dynamic?

```
 waterStatus: function () {
                    document.getElementById('water-status').innerText = this.water;
                },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the new total value, so the condition will work:

```
....
} else if (this.water + Number(addWater) < 400) {
  addWater = Number(addWater);
  this.water += addWater;
...
```

**Update**

I think you should change the parameter `water` to `addWater` in the `emptyWater` function:

```
emptyWater: function (addWater) {
  if (this.water > addWater) {
    this.water -= addWater;
    this.waterStatus();
    ...
```

You can use it in the `addWater` function, as:

```
...
} else if (this.water < 400) {
  addWater = Number(addWater);
  this.water += addWater;
  this.emptyWater(addWater);
...
```

And the `waterStatus` would be:

```
waterStatus: function () {
  document.getElementById('water-status').innerText = this.water;
},
```

Comment: Yes! The first function works now, thank you!
I'm still figuring out the parameter one. Because if I write it the way you did it says it's undefined, so it still bugs me.

Comment: In your `emptyWater` function, where the `addWater` variable comes from?

Comment: I updated the question with the first method where I define this.water. 
Yea, not sure either, I messed up that part, because I should check if the current status of the water is bigger than the value we forwarder to prompt, and that if it is subtract the added value from the current.

Comment: Where/how do you call the `emptyWater` function?

Comment: When I'm making coffee, I should call eg. ShortEspresso button, which costs 30 credits and it is necessary to check whether the machine has enough credit, if there is no I should call emptyCredit and forward it 30 to write out the message that there is no credit and to do a return, and it is necessary to examine whether there is enough water
if not call emptyWater and pass it 20 to print a message that there is no water and do a return. The same thing I do with milk, and credit.

Comment: If you modify the emptyWater as I suggested, I think you should call `this.emptyWater(addWater)` at the end of the `addWater` fn.

Comment: !Ok that makes sense. I have just one more question, and thank you for all of this, you helped A LOT. My value in this.water is the value I predefined in object, then I made the method waterStatus and it collected those values. I think you tried to tell me to do so but I didn't understand, how to make waterStatus dynamic function, so it kind of resets when I want to add value through the prompt. I don't know if I'm making any sense?

Comment: Yes! This solves a lot! I still have some methods to finish, but with the help of this it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. It should be dynamic if you are using `this.water`, just call `waterStatus` when you need an update.